# Compare 2 arrays in Php

Tags: php, arrays

I have created a 2 arrays such as below. My goal is to compare these two arrays and echo something IF THERE IS a value in array2 that is NOT in array1.

```
$array1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$array2 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 6);
```

Comment: first google if you can't find answer then ask question here.

Comment: How about an element of array1 that's not in array2?

Comment: @RonniSkansing That's a biased view I disagree with, sure the OP asked something common, but why blame it on the ones answering? Also, please define 'effortless code'.

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger Yea, you are right, I am biased (it is the nature of my opinion), and I can not say I have not answered anything that really should have been closed. But come on... This should be so easy to see for a experienced SO member, why award the user with answers and answers with points? for effortless code as in the OP's two lines of array (not the answers) with not even a try or a speculation.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you should use [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/array_diff); `array_diff($a, $b)` returns the values of `$a` that are not present in `$b`.

So:

```
if (($diff = array_diff($array2, $array1))) {
    printf(
      "Values in array2 that are not present in array1: %s\n", 
      join(' ', $diff)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [`array_diff()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php).

```
<?php
$array1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$array2 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 6);

print_r(array_diff($array2,$array1));
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [4] => 6
)
```

**`EDIT :`**

> This is actually the opposite of what I am looking for. What I want is
> to scan the array1 to check whether the value of '6' does exist in
> array. If it doesn't echo something

```
<?php
$array1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$array2 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 6);

foreach($array2 as $val)
{
    if(in_array($val,$array1))
    {
        echo "$val is available in array1<br>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "$val is not available in array1<br>";
    }
}
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
1 is available in array1
2 is available in array1
3 is available in array1
4 is available in array1
6 is not available in array1
```

Comment: This is actually the opposite of what I am looking for. What I want is to scan the array1 to check whether the value of '6' does exist in array which it doesnt. If it doesn't echo something.

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_diff](https://www.php.net/array_diff).

```
array_diff($array2, $array1);
```

Comment: This is actually the opposite of what I am looking for. What I want is to scan the array1 to check whether the value of '6' does exist in array which it doesnt. If it doesn't echo something.

Comment: @user3135626 This is exactly what this should do.

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_diff](https://www.php.net/array_diff)

```
<?php
$array1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$array2 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 6);
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);

print_r($result);
?>
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [4] => 6
)
```

if your want get the same values in array use [array_intersect](https://www.php.net/array_intersect)

```
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
```